# Using integrals to evaluate the O(n) of sums

Tags: integration, discrete-mathematics, summation

Taking an unusual approach to finding the big O notation of a sum:

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k$$

Then let $g(n) = \int_{0}^{n}xdx $. Could we then say that because $g(n)\simeq f(n)$, that $f(n)\in O(g)$.
Now evaluating $g(n)$,

$$g(n) = \int_{0}^{n}xdx = \left[ \frac{1}{2}x^2 \right]_{0}^{n} = \frac{1}{2}n^2$$

$\therefore g(n)\in O(n^2)$ and $f(n) \in O(n^2)$

Does this logic stack up? and is it possibly useful for more complex sums. I am aware of other ways to find the big O of $f(n)$, however this was my first instinct. Id be grateful for any insight.

Comment: what is the definition of $g(x)\simeq f(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach to finding the big O notation of the sum function $f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k$ is interesting. However, I would like to point out that your conclusion that $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ based on the approximation $g(n)\simeq f(n)$ is not valid.

To see why, consider the definition of big O notation: $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ if there exist positive constants $C$ and $n_0$ such that $|f(n)|\leq C|g(n)|$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Your approximation $g(n)\simeq f(n)$ does not give you a precise upper bound on $f(n)$ in terms of $g(n)$. In other words, you cannot conclude that $f(n)\leq Cg(n)$ for some constant $C$.

However, you can still use your approach to find the big O notation of $f(n)$ by comparing it to a known function that grows at the same rate. In this case, you correctly calculated that $g(n)\in O(n^2)$, so we can conclude that $f(n)\in O(n^2)$ as well.

To see why, note that $f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, which is a quadratic function of $n$. Therefore, we can write $f(n)=an^2+bn+c$ for some constants $a$, $b$, and $c$. Since $f(n)$ is a quadratic function and $g(n)\in O(n^2)$, we can conclude that $f(n)\in O(n^2)$ as well.

In summary, your approach of approximating the sum function with an integral and then comparing it to a known function can be a useful technique for finding the big O notation of more complex sums. However, it is important to remember that the approximation does not give a precise upper bound, so you still need to verify that the function you compare it to is indeed a tight upper bound.